# RegExp word matching using variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to find the count of matches as well as replace occurrence of matches. Case is insensitive. Also I need to use a variable instead of the actual string so that I can reuse the logic.

**Sample text:** Her Husband leads in-country business audit teams across Southern Europe and reports to her.

***Expected outcome***

**Count:** 2

**Result text** *should be* "xxx Husband leads in-country business audit teams across Southern Europe and reports to xxx."

Note 'her' in the Southern is ignored.

```
var testdata = "Her Husband leads in-country business audit teams across Southern Europe and reports to her.";
var searchstring = thisarray[i]; // e.g.: "her";
var search_regexp = new RegExp(searchstring, "\g\i");
var count = testate.match(search_regexp).length;
var resulttext = testdata.replace(search_regexp,"xxx");
```

My way of doing is not working properly as it is finding her in the Southern as well. What is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry white space is not the ideal answer, but non word characters. e.g. `/\W*her\W/ig`

Comment: instead of her can you help me using the variable.../\W*[searchstring]\W/ig is not working

Comment: `var search_regexp = newRegExp(/\W*[variable]\W/ig)`

Comment: @char it didnt work... I think I was not clear and so I have amended my second line of code to clarify my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `var searchstring` is just a plain her, so it'll find anything that has `h e r` in consective order, add either white spaces before and after or, better yet, boundary `\b\`

So it should look like this: `\bher\b`

Edit:

use this:

```
var a_word = "her";
var searchstring = '\\b' + a_word + '\\b';
var search_regexp = new RegExp(searchstring, "gi");

var match1 = testdata.match(search_regexp);
```

The reason why you need `\\b` is because the `\\` escapse to `\` afterwards, which makes `\b`.

Here's the jsfiddle that shows RegExp and no RegExp: https://jsfiddle.net/1r2jyodo/1/

Comment: The thing is that who do i do what you suggested with variables. \bsearchstring\b is giving error

Comment: Changed it up for clarification.

Comment: I like this answer. It's more concise than what I Suggested.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. The only issue here is that i cannot hardcode 'her' as it is a variable. I have modified the problem to demonstrate it var searchstring = thisarray[i]; // e.g.: "her";